# What is the best way to say "Under New Management"?

Tags: translation

The three options I have found are:

- 根据新的管理
- 新的管理团队
- 管理团队新血液

Do either of these sound good, or does anybody have a better suggestion?
Can it possibly be said in only 4 characters?

For context, these are going on business cards

[image]

But I'm printing out over 1,000 of these, so I want to make sure I don't mess up

Comment: No team necessary I don't think?  That was just a suggestion from a friend

Comment: I can't completely understand any of the English version or Chinese versions. What do you mean by "under new management"? (And for the idea of design, let me ask) Why do you need to put it on the business cards?

Comment: I took over a business, but the previous owner had a horrible reputation.  He basically stole from the customers over and over.  I can't afford to change the business name at the moment, so I need to make it clear that it is owned by a new person.

Comment: If it's so important, make it as a slogan! Plain description doesn't make much sense to customers. You need something like "新团队，新体验" to emphasize what customers can get. And I think you should hire a better graphic designer, if you do it by yourself, read Robin Williams's *The Non-Designer's Design Book*.

Comment: jukuu：（公司）由新人管理，（公司） 在新人管理下

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a slightly more formal register, since it's going to be printed on your business card? I suggest "嶄新管理團隊". On a side note, I agree that the design has plenty of room for improvement.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to do a second round of advertisements later-- but right now I just can't budget a professional designer :\  This ended up being the final design: http://imgur.com/geHiBsL

Answer (score 2):

老店新张！I saw it used in many instances in China when the owner changes.